# BigDecimal toEngineeringString not working

Tags: java, android

I would to use `toEngineeringString()` but it doesn't works :

```
Log.v("smslms",BigDecimal.valueOf(1_000_0000_000_000_000L).toEngineeringString());`
```

output :

```
09-11 16:26:12.221  18492-18492/skarwild.game V/smslms﹕ 10000000000000000
```

Comment: Note that one of your "sections" in the number has four 0s in, btw. Did you mean it to?

Answer (score 3):

It's behaving exactly as [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toEngineeringString--):

> Returns a string that represents the BigDecimal as described in the toString() method, except that if exponential notation is used, the power of ten is adjusted to be a multiple of three (engineering notation) such that the integer part of nonzero values will be in the range 1 through 999.

Now `toString()` specifies:

> A standard canonical string form of the BigDecimal is created as though by the following steps: first, the absolute value of the unscaled value of the BigDecimal is converted to a string in base ten using the characters '0' through '9' with no leading zeros (except if its value is zero, in which case a single '0' character is used).
>
> Next, an adjusted exponent is calculated; this is the negated scale, plus the number of characters in the converted unscaled value, less one. That is, -scale+(ulength-1), where ulength is the length of the absolute value of the unscaled value in decimal digits (its precision).
>
> If the scale is greater than or equal to zero and the adjusted exponent is greater than or equal to -6, the number will be converted to a character form without using exponential notation.

In our case the scale is 0, so the adjusted exponent is 16 (or something thereabouts). Therefore the value is converted to a character form without using exponential notation.